# Why use jQuery filter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-filter

Why is there a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function in jQuery when you can get and show / hide the elements by class?

```
$('.yourClass');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you have some elements that you'd like to work with doesn't mean that they're in the DOM. Consider this contrived example:

```
var $els = $('<div class="a"></div><div class="b"></div>');
console.log($('.a'));
console.log($els.find('.a'));
console.log($els.filter('.a'));​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/h3GMB/

The first one, `$('.a')`, gives you nothing because `$els` aren't in the DOM yet. The second one also gives you nothing because [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) searches *descendents*. Only the third one will give you what you're looking for because [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) reduces:

> the set of matched elements to those that match the selector [...]

This sort of manipulation of things not in the DOM is fairly common when preparing template chunks for the DOM. The difference between `filter` and `find` is also fairly important even when the elements in question *are* in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As from the document:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .filter() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against each element; all elements matching the selector will be included in the result.
>
> Consider a page with a simple list on it:
>
> We can apply this method to the set of list items:

```
$('li').filter(':even').css('background-color', 'red');
```

> The result of this call is a red background for items 1, 3, and 5, as they match the selector (recall that :even and :odd use 0-based indexing).

The filter function is used to filter the result of your original query into specific elements.

But if you are referring to `.hide()` and `.show()`, it's a choice you have, instead of splitting your code into both css and javascript, you have a couple of methods that are cross browser to do the job instead.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` allows you to filter part of the set you have, let's say we have a list of items, and to all items I want to add a class, but to part of it I want to add another class:

```
$('#mylist li').addClass('someclass').filter('.someotherclass').addClass('filtered');
```

I could have split this up in two queries.